# Google OAuth resulting in server_error

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

When my window loads I run the following code:

```
gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
    gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: "MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    });
});
```

After the initialization completes and after the user clicks a sign-in button, I run the following code:

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
    .signIn({ scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl" })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log("Sign-in successful");
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error signing in");
        console.error(err);
    })
;
```

I get the following error in my console:

> `error: "server_error"`

[image]

---

#### How do I fix this?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me:

HTML

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
await gapi.client.init({
    clientId: "CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/INSERT_SCOPE_HERE",
});

try {
    res = await gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
} catch (err) {
    console.error("Error signing in");
    console.error(err);
    return;
}
        
console.log("Sign-in successful");
console.log(res);
```